# Find exact running time in Selenium IDE html code

Tags: selenium-ide

I am doing record and playback in Selenium IDE.I need to start time and end time to calculate total running time.Is there any way to get time changing html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

storeEval can be of help here!
Run this as your source code in selenium IDE.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://192.168.0.118:8080" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>{new Date()}</td>
    <td>Cur_time</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${Cur_time}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>{new Date()}</td>
    <td>Cur_time2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${Cur_time2}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>{(storedVars[&quot;Cur_time2&quot;].getTime() - storedVars[&quot;Cur_time&quot;].getTime())/1000}</td>
    <td>diff</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${diff}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

You should get the following output:

```
[info] Playing test case Untitled
[info] Executing: |storeEval | {new Date()} | Cur_time |
[info] script is: {new Date()}
[info] Executing: |echo | ${Cur_time} | |
[info] echo: Fri Nov 25 2016 14:27:37 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
[info] Executing: |pause | 5000 | |
[info] Executing: |storeEval | {new Date()} | Cur_time2 |
[info] script is: {new Date()}
[info] Executing: |echo | ${Cur_time2} | |
[info] echo: Fri Nov 25 2016 14:27:43 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
[info] Executing: |storeEval | {(storedVars["Cur_time2"].getTime() - storedVars["Cur_time"].getTime())/1000} | diff |
[info] script is: {(storedVars["Cur_time2"].getTime() - storedVars["Cur_time"].getTime())/1000}
[info] Executing: |echo | ${diff} | |
[info] echo: 5.06
[info] Test case passed
[info] Test suite completed: 1 played, all passed!
```

*[info] echo: 5.06* means your test time was 5.06 seconds. You should place your whole test between the two storeEval calls for *Cur_time* and *Cur_time2* to capture the start time and end time. Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad to know it helped! Please go through this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work